# Asynchronous PHP function calling

Tags: php, function, asynchronous, php-5.6

I have a function that writes it into a file.

```
public function write($type = "error", $mensaje = "") { 
    $this->file = fopen($this->filePath.$this->fileName, "a+"); 

    if ($this->file == null) { 
        trigger_error("Error: No file", E_USER_ERROR); 
    } else { 
        fwrite($this->file, $type." ".$mensaje."\n");
    } 
}
```

I need to call this function from another php file say index.php

```
function test() {
    write("testing done");
    echo "done";
}
```

I want the write function to be called from index.php asynchronously so the current execution doesn't stop or block if the write fails.

Comment: You might perhaps find this of interest / use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls?rq=1

Comment: Write the above function in a class and call the class to the index.php

Comment: @SobinAugustine that could block the execution

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP does not support multithreading so there is not really a way to do this easily. You could build something using cron or something, but that would be too broad to explain here. That being said, your `write` function doesn't look so bad to just call it in the main thread.

Comment: maybe use pthreads, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27364939/1855357

Comment: @SobinAugustine ye, just found out about that just now

Comment: Using a distributed architecture is probably the correct answer for such problems, but this is beyond the scope to explain in detail here. Look into n-tier architectures, Gearman, queue/worker setups and the like.

Answer (score 0):

with phptreads ( http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php ), something like

```
class writerThread extends Thread {
public function __construct($type="error",$message=''){
  $this->type=$type;
$this->message=$message;
}

public function run(){
   file_put_contents($filename,$this->type.$this->message);
}
}

$writer=new WriterThread("testing done");
$writer->start();
```